# How to include html code into Jade file?

Tags: node.js, pug

I get from database some html:

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">Hello Summernote</span>
```

How can I add this html into div using Jade? When I tried to add it I got something like that.

```
<div>"<span style="text-decoration: underline; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">Hello Summernote</span>"</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jade offers the ability to render 'regular' html inside a template. In your router (in the example it's express):

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('default', {text: content});
});
```

`text` is in this case the html from your database. In jade you have to wrap your element:

```
#content
        p !{text}
```

`!{}` will stop the rendering process of the content and use the plain html from your database. The `p` tag is just an example to display it.